# ESLint doesn't see redux/redux-thunk types

Tags: typescript, redux, eslint, redux-thunk

I am adding ESLint rules to the project. Project uses typescript. There is a problem with Redux/Redux-Thunk types. When I try to import any type from Redux or Redux-Thunk ESLint gives me an error:

```
import { Action, AnyAction, applyMiddleware, combineReducers, createStore } from 'redux';
import thunkMiddleware, { ThunkAction, ThunkDispatch } from 'redux-thunk';
```

ESLInt error:

```
>> Action not found in 'redux'
>> AnyAction not found in 'redux'
>> ThunkAction not found in 'redux-thunk'
>> ThunkDispatch not found in 'redux-thunk'
```

My first though was to install types for [Redux](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/redux) and [Thunk](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/redux-thunk), however both tell, that redux now comes with types automatically and I don't have to install them separately.

I also have to mention, that application works well, types are there, it's only an issue with ESLint.

I did the followint workaround in .eslintrc:

```
settings: {
    'import/core-modules': ['redux', 'redux-thunk']
}
```

Question:
Since I would like to avoid workarounds, what is the right way to set this up?

**UPD**

My eslintrc:

```
{
  "root": true,
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  "ignorePatterns": ["*.html", "*.png", "*.svg", "*.ico", "*.ttf", "*.txt"],
  "extends": [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/eslint-recommended",
    "plugin:import/errors",
    "plugin:import/warnings",
    "plugin:jest-dom/recommended",
    "plugin:prettier/recommended",
    "plugin:react/recommended",
    "plugin:react-hooks/recommended",
    "plugin:react-redux/recommended"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "prettier",
    "react",
    "react-hooks",
    "jest-dom",
    "unused-imports",
    "react-redux",
    "@typescript-eslint"
  ],
  "env": {
    "jest": true,
    "browser": true,
    "es6": true,
    "es2017": true,
    "es2020": true,
    "es2021": true
  },
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": 6,
    "sourceType": "module",
    "ecmaFeatures": {
      "jsx": true
    }
  },
  "rules": {
    "linebreak-style": 0,
    "no-shadow": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-shadow": ["error"],
    "arrow-body-style": ["error", "always"],
    "import/first": 2,
    "import/newline-after-import": 0,
    "import/no-dynamic-require": 0,
    "import/no-named-as-default": 0,
    "import/no-unresolved": 2,
    "import/no-webpack-loader-syntax": 0,
    "import/prefer-default-export": 0,
    "max-len": 0,
    "newline-per-chained-call": 0,
    "no-confusing-arrow": 0,
    "no-console": 2,
    "no-restricted-syntax": [
      "error",
      {
        "selector": "ForInStatement",
        "message":
          "for..in loops iterate over the entire prototype chain, which is virtually never what you want. Use Object.{keys,values,entries}, and iterate over the resulting array."
      },
      {
        "selector": "WithStatement",
        "message": "`with` is disallowed in strict mode because it makes code impossible to predict and optimize."
      }
    ],
    "no-unused-vars": "off",
    "unused-imports/no-unused-imports": "error",
    "no-use-before-define": 0,
    "prefer-template": 2,
    "react/destructuring-assignment": 0,
    "react/jsx-closing-tag-location": 0,
    "react/forbid-prop-types": 0,
    "react/jsx-indent": [2, 2],
    "react/jsx-first-prop-new-line": [2, "multiline"],
    "react/jsx-filename-extension": 0,
    "react/jsx-no-target-blank": 0,
    "react/jsx-props-no-spreading": 0,
    "react/jsx-uses-vars": 2,
    "react/jsx-no-duplicate-props": [2, { "ignoreCase": false }],
    "react/require-default-props": 0,
    "react/require-extension": 0,
    "react/self-closing-comp": 0,
    "react/sort-comp": 0,
    "react/state-in-constructor": 0,
    "react/static-property-placement": 0,
    "react-hooks/rules-of-hooks": "error",
    "react-hooks/exhaustive-deps": "warn"
  },
  "overrides": [
    {
      "files": ["**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx"],
      "extends": [
        "eslint:recommended",
        "plugin:@typescript-eslint/eslint-recommended",
        "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended"
      ],
      "plugins": ["@typescript-eslint"]
    }
  ]
}
```

If I add `settings` to find tsconfig:

```
  "settings": {
    "import/resolver": {
      "typescript": {
        "project": "tsconfig.json"
      }
    }
  }
```

ESLint error changes to:

`Resolve error: typescript with invalid interface loaded as resolver`

Answer (score 0):

I can not reprocuce the error:

**.eslintrc**

```
{
  "root": true,
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  "plugins": [
    "@typescript-eslint"
  ],
  "extends": [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/eslint-recommended",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended"
  ]
}
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "redux": "^4.1.2",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.4.1",
    "typescript": "^4.5.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.9.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.9.1",
    "eslint": "^8.7.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext .ts"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! I've tried your .eslintrc, can confirm there are no errors. However, I would like to use much more plugins and thus my `eslint` is much longer. I've added my config to the questions.